# Displaying front side empty with one file attached problem

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style

There is a problem in my custom theme. I add all css and js files in functons.php file.
my all files work properly. But my plugin.css file creates problem, when i add this file there is not shown anything at the front side on my site. But when i check file in view page source my file attached here. I cannot understand what is the problem.
There is my finctions.php code:

There is my plugin.css file:

view-source:http://192.168.1.125/kindergarten/wp-content/themes/kindergarten/css/plugin.css?ver=5.5

Comment: Can you tell me the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved, I add all files in header so its create problems now i add js files in footer so my problem is solve.